# Unity. After downloading my rawimage is still blank

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rawimage

Hi My scene name is a game.In that scene I am having A main panel that's name is ITEMCONTAINER. In item container I am having a panel whoes name is ITEM. I attached a script in ITEM PANEL. IN that script i am having a game object public,a raw image ,text and how many times loop will continue are public.
In the place of game object i attached my prefab,that contain 1 text and 2 rawimage. 
in place of text i attached text component of prefab and same like raw image.
When I run the game the text value I am getting correctly but rawimage is showing blank in runtime.Here i am running my loop 3 times and all three times it create clone of my prefab panel as a child in **itempanel** 
I want rawimage dynamic at my run time

output

[image]

prefab

[image]

1. image= in this image , it contains output.here rawimage is blank but text valuecoming perfectly
2. image = it is my prefab that prefab will be clone during runtime, here it shows image but during runtime , in clone it shows blank

   ```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;   
   using UnityEngine.UI;    
   public class DynamicData : MonoBehaviour {      
   public GameObject prefab; 
   public Text name;       
   public int numberToCreate;

   public RawImage profile;


   void Start () {

       for (int i = 0; i < numberToCreate; i++)
       {
           name.text = "a"+i;
           StartCoroutine( ImageDownload( profile));

           Instantiate <GameObject>(prefab, transform);
       }

   }
   IEnumerator ImageDownload ( RawImage img) {

       WWW www = new WWW("https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg");

       yield return www;

       Texture2D texure = new Texture2D (1, 1);
       texure.LoadImage (www.bytes);
       texure.Apply ();
       img.texture = texure;

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: It's unity not unity container and the language is c#

Comment: yes. I saw in previous post u help one people.please help me ,if u want i can send my unity package to u

Comment: What is the prefab and where is this script attached?

Comment: wait 2 min i will send the link of my unity package

Comment: here prefab will come on runtime. and script is attached to item panel.that item panel is inside of item container

Comment: I will not download package. We help people not download their project. That's what I do as a last resort. You want to instantiate a prefab and set the image to the downloaded image? I just don't understand what you are even doing so please edit your question and explain.

Comment: i just want rawimage will be download and it will show during runtime.If my loop is running 5 times,then 5 image.

Comment: here is thelink https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WC5oM3eq1tX2c0dWlUSGRQNGc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the downloaded image to the profile variable which is not a variable from the instantiated Object. In the loop, you need to get the child of each instantiated Object with `transform.Find("profile")` then get the `RawImage` component attached to it with `GetComponent` and pass it to the `ImageDownload` function.

Replace your `for` loop with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberToCreate; i++)
{
    name.text = "a" + i;

    GameObject instance = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefab, transform);
    //Get RawImage of the current instance
    RawImage rImage = instance.transform.Find("profile").GetComponent<RawImage>();
    StartCoroutine(ImageDownload(rImage));
}
```

---

Please rename `public Text name;` to something else like `public Text userName;` because the name is already declared in `MonoBehavior` you derived your script from.

Comment: Thanks alot. You helped me.I was struggling from past 1 week. 1 more question, suppose my rawimage have some tag then how i will call and do operation like

Comment: `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("yourtag").GetComponent<RawImage>();`....You are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your help.Here my tag is Profile for rawimage, Then how i will apply in in same program.Can you show me code

Comment: Please create new question about tag since this is totally a different issue. I will see if I can help.

Comment: here you are doing : RawImage rImage = instance.transform.Find("profile").GetComponent<RawImage>();

so here you are finding by his name,so i want like find by tag